# What does this error means in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Building target “testjson” of project “testjson” with configuration “Debug” — (2 errors)
    Checking Dependencies
error: There is no SDK with specified name or path '/Users/xcdfs/Library/SDKs/JSON/iphonesimulator.sdk'
error: There is no SDK with specified name or path '/Users/xcdfs/Library/SDKs/JSON/iphonesimulator.sdk'
        error: There is no SDK with specified name or path '/Users/xcdfs/Library/SDKs/JSON/iphonesimulator.sdk'
        error: There is no SDK with specified name or path '/Users/xcdfs/Library/SDKs/JSON/iphonesimulator.sdk'
Build failed (2 errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you added your JSON library as a framework instead of (I'm guessing) a static or shared library. Which JSON library are you using and how are you configuring the linker to see it in your build settings?